# java Querydsl BooleanBuilder OneToMany query

Tags: java, spring, jpa, querydsl

Using spring boot and spring JPA I have a Receipt model which has a oneToMany relationship with Store mode:

```
@Entity
public class Receipt extends Base {

    //other model fields

    @Column(name="email")
    private String Email;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="store_id")
    private Store Store;

    //getters & setters 
}
```

and I want to use BooleanBuilder to find a receipt that has an email and belongs to specific store. As for email I can simple say

```
where.and(q.Email.eq("some@email.com"));
```

but I don't know how can I search with the email & store Id. something like

```
where.and(q.Email.eq("some@email.com")).and(q.Store.id.eq(1));
```

I know I can get the store object from the database and then pass it to `where` but is that the only way?

Comment: care to share with us what is "BooleanBuilder" (i.e what package is it in)?

Comment: @NeilStockton It's a querydsl package. forgot to mention it but edited the question

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me once was to map the foreign key separately:

```
@Column(name="store_id")
private Integer storeId;
```

You should then be able to call

```
where(q.Email.eq("some@email.com")).and(q.storeId.eq(1));
```